# IIS 8.5 Web.config for named SQL Server instance on alternate port

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio, iis

I recently upgraded to Windows Server 2012 from 2003. It was a big IIS jump from 6 to 8.5. I cannot seem to get a named SQL Server instance on an alternate port to work in my ASP.net 4.0 website.

The connection string I am using is:

```
<add name="MyConn" 
     connectionString="Server=192.168.12.5\stage,7839;Database=mydb;uid=myun;pwd=mypw;" />
```

When the website tries to load in the browser, I get the following error:

> [HttpException (0x80004005): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.)]

We've checked firewall settings to no avail. Is the syntax correct in the above example? I've done numerous searches and found examples of people using

```
192.168.12.5:7839\stage
```

or

```
192.168.12.5\stage;port=7839;
```

but both of those give syntax errors.

I need some confirmation on the correct syntax for the `web.config` file. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Can you access your database using SQL server management studio?

Comment: yes, I can from the SQL server itself.

Answer (score 0):

Can you go to SQL Server > Configuration Tools > Configuration Manager and see if that instance is really named what you think it is?

You should see something like this:

[image]

The entries `SQL Server (instacename)` on the right hand side show you what instances you have - they should be in state **running**, and the instance name is in the brackets. If it's `MSSQLSERVER`, then it's an unnamed default instance - otherwise it's the instance name. Is your instance name correct, as expected - and running?

Comment: Yes, it's correct. I can connect to the database when on the local SQL server. Can you confirm what is the proper connection strIng for the Web.config using the info I provided?